# WordPress custom URL guessing before the default guessing

Tags: wordpress

I believe a solution to this would apply to any WordPress core function, but this is a specific example I'm having struggle with.

I want to make some custom URL guessing, before the default one. It would look something like this:

```
function custom_redirect_guessing( $requested_url = null, $do_redirect = true ) {
    // My custom logic

    // If none of my logic checks out, execute the default one.
    default_guessing();
 }

 add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'custom_redirect_guessing' );
```

But this of course doesn't work.

My main goal is to fix URLs coming from the previous website, for example:

```
example.com/fr/news/slug => example.com/fr/slug
```

This would normally work, but my client's previous website has all the slugs in EN, so WP's automatic guessing redirects all trafic to EN, instead of keeping the visitor in the respect language.

Currently, WP's automatic guessing is doing something like this (because FR and EN share the same slug):

```
example.com/fr/news/slug => example.com/en/slug
```

Any ideas on how to do fix this?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Comment: @disinfor I used the plugin you recommended to redirect a regex from `^/([a-z]{2})/news/([a-z0-9-]+)$` to `/$1/$2`, but it isn't redirecting. Do you see anything wrong in my expression?

Comment: You might need to escape those forward `/`, but I'm not necessarily a regex expert.